# QtRuby on Mac Os and ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, macos, qt

i would really like to get down to some ruby programming with QT in Mac OS. I have tried lots of different things to install Qt on Mac os and develop there, but whatever i do does not seem to work. I've tried gems and even source, but i can't get it to work.

Has anyone created the same programming environment in Mac OS successfully ? If so, can you give some insight on how to set it up, maybe a good up-to date resource or something ? I can't find something that works.

P.S. I have a 64-bit core 2 duo processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fork of the QtBindings gem which is hacked to build on OS X https://github.com/deadprogrammer/qtbindings